# What tools (e.g. IDEs, Debuggers) are there for complex Arduino projects?

Tags: c, arduino

I'd like to develop a network based application for the Arduino platform. The examples shipped with a Wi-Fi Shield library are all multifile sketches with a network part implemented in C. I'd like to figure out how to implement the network portion in a way regular C/C++ development is conducted (with a decent IDE and step-by-step debugger).

I noticed [WiShield](http://asynclabs.com/wiki/index.php?title=WiShield_2.0) is build on top of the [uIP library](http://www.sics.se/~adam/uip/) ((an open source full TCP/IP stack implementation for resource-constrained embedded devices)) and greatly influenced by it. Smart folks implemented DHCP and zero configuration implementations on top of it. How do people execute projects of such complexity and what tools are being used?

Comment: I use AVR Studio 4, it took a bit of effort to understand how to upload the programs to my Arduino, but otherwise I like it. With a supported in-circuit debugger you can debug the actual arduino, or you can run it on the AVR emulator (which I guess is less feasible when there is other circuitry involved.) I don't know what your requirements are, but the AVR Studio uses Eclipse as its "shell".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for some Arduino emulator? I think these two should get you started.
[Emulino](https://github.com/ghewgill/emulino)
[Simavr](http://gitorious.org/simavr)

Answer (score 1):

Use the simple programming software that can easily work with arduino chips but don't make your project in complex situation putting some complex programs.